# Cannot install OCI8 in ubuntu 12.04 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh

Tags: command-line, apache2, php, oracle

I am installing oracle in ubuntu with the help of this tutorial

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PHPOracle

I have already installed php,apache2, build-essential,php5-dev php-pear libaio1,php5-dev,php-pear,libaio-dev,

I have downloaded the packaged `instantclient-sdk-linux-12.1.0.2.0.zip`, `instantclient-basic-linux-12.1.0.2.0.zip`

also i changed all the `11.1` to `12.1` and  `_11_1` to `_12_1` accordingly in my installation process

I did all the steps till

`sudo ln -s libclntsh.so.11.1 libclntsh.so` mine is `sudo ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so`

and i did

`sudo pecl install oci8`

the terminal only asked for ORACLE_HOME location and i gave

`instantclient,/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_2`

see my terminal log, what am i doing wrong here, please help me

```
mukund@mukund-gapblue:/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1$ sudo pecl install oci8
downloading oci8-2.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download oci8-2.0.8.tgz (190,854 bytes)
.........................................done: 190,854 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant  /client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] : instantclient,/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8
running: /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/configure --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 5.5.9, ok
checking OCI8 DTrace support... no
checking size of long int... 8
checking checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1
checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... /usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include
checking Oracle Instant Client library version compatibility... 12.1
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp  /pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c -o oci8.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build- rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp /pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_lob.c -o oci8_lob.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_lob.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_lob.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_statement.c -o oci8_statement.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_statement.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_statement.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_collection.c -o oci8_collection.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include  /php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_collection.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_collection.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c -o oci8_interface.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1 /sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8_interface.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8_interface.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear- build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext /date/lib -I/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o oci8.la -export- dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootklUHg0/oci8-2.0.8 /modules  oci8.lo oci8_lob.lo oci8_statement.lo oci8_collection.lo oci8_interface.lo -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local  /lib/instantclient_12_1 -L/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1 -lclntsh
libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/oci8.o .libs/oci8_lob.o .libs/oci8_statement.o    .libs/oci8_collection.o .libs/oci8_interface.o   -L/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1 -lclntsh  -O2 -Wl,-rpath    -Wl,/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1   -Wl,-soname -Wl,oci8.so -o .libs/oci8.so
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so when searching for  -lclntsh
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [oci8.la] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
mukund@mukund-gapblue:/usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1$
```

Comment: The message `skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so` suggests that the version(s) of the zipped `instantclient` packages that you downloaded are not the correct ones for your system architecture (e.g. 32-bit versus 64-bit)

Comment: yup, i got it, installed 32bit oci8 in 64bit OS! Am a fool!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the error was

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb
```

Problem was solved when I installed the relevant packages related to lusb namely libusb's developer version. I would say that perhaps installing the packages solve the error.

Hope this helps. :)